# Robot framework files through Jenkins which is running on Linux amazon instance.

Tags: jenkins

How to use the Jenkins servers running on linux machine. Case is i have installed jenkin server on amazon instance but my Robot framework and files are present on the Windows machine. How i can access Robot framework files through Jenkins which is running on Linux amazon instance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a moment to take a tour. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

If jenkins is running on a linux machine, the robot files also need to be on the linux machine.